# Convert ASCII characters to hex escaped strings

Tags: python, struct

I was reading in a file from Python. I opened this file and used 'rb' to read the bytes. When I read them off, say:

```
f.read(1)
```

it would output something like this

```
b'\x50'
```

So my question is, when I tried a longer string like this

```
f.read(24)
```

I got this:

```
b'R\x00S\x00S\x00Q\x00S\x00O\x00N\x00P\x00S\x00M\x00R\x00P\x00
```

You notice that there are [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters mixed into the hex. I would want the R to be displayed as \x52.

How do I do that?

Comment: What for? It's still the same value.

Comment: not when trying to feed it to struct.unpack()

Comment: Yes, even then. `>>> b'A' == b'\x41'` `True`

Comment: maybe you are right. I was just trying this and it kept giving me errors. for some reason, it just worked now. I have no idea what was different :( this makes me feel like I didnt look hard enough

Answer (score 6):

```
print(''.join('\\x%02x' % c for c in B))
```